# Pull Tags But Not as Links

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, tags

I'm trying to take a list of tags and list them on the page but without linking to their archive page.

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'visits', 'Visits ', ', ', ' ' );
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms). I've adapted the following from an example on that page:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'visits' );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 

    $visits_name = array();

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $visits_name[] = $term->name;
    }
    $terms_list = join( ", ", $visits_name );
    echo $terms_list;
endif;
```

**EDIT:**

Using [`wp_list_pluck`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck), as suggested by [Telos](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31073/t31os), is much easier:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'visits' );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
  echo join( ',', wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'name' ) );
endif;
```

Comment: You could consider using `wp_list_pluck` to do the name plucking for you. Oh, and your if condition is not closed.

Comment: Yes, lame copy/paste from the codex. Thanks for the `wp_list_pluck`!

Answer (score 0):

List all the terms in a custom taxonomy, without a link:

```
$terms = get_terms("my_taxonomy");
 $count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";
    }
     echo "</ul>";
 }
```

List all the terms, with link to term archive, separated by an interpunct (·). (language specific, WPML method):

```
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'my_term' );
$terms = get_terms('my_term', $args);
$count = count($terms); $i=0;
if ($count > 0) {
    $cape_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="/term-base/' . $term->slug . '" title="' .sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        if ($count != $i)
          $term_list .= ' &middot; '; 
        else 
           $term_list .= '</p>';
    }    
echo $term_list;}
```

For more details: [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).

Comment: Thanks. How can I put a comma between the terms rather than a new line? I'm messing up the <li>

Comment: Please follow this URL : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

if you are not gating this then please let me know.

Comment: The user is fetching terms associated with a post ID, `get_terms` will not be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd use this :

```
echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'visits', 'Visits ', ', ', ' ' ));
```

EDIT : We use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to deactivate link. This has to be used within the loop.

Comment: "This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content", which I am sure you don't want. Please try to make your answers more substantial. Add an explanation of your solution, links to the codex or other sources...

Comment: Am I clear enough?